# Git + Unity is corrupting my files

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project in a git repo. I did a pull of someone else's code (that is working on their end). Now, Unity is going crazy, creating a bunch of empty objects and breaking apart my prefabs and giving me compiler errors like:

```
"Unable to parse YAML file: [mapping values are not allowed in this context] at line 1
"
```

and

```
CheckConsistency: GameObject does not reference component Transform. Fixing.
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()
```

What on earth is going on here?  Did something get put into git that shouldn't have (and if so, how do I recover?)

Edit:

Okay, it looks like there was some merge issues in some Unity files, like ProjectVersion.txt Fixing that didn't fully fix the problem, though. I ended up nuking my version from orbit and cloning a fresh copy from git and that fixed it.

Comment: Is line endings being changed perhaps?

Comment: Check your `.gitattributes` how the files are transfered/compared.